# Calcular medias para cada combinación de variables independientes utilizando tapply

Tags: r

Tengo un grupo de datos dat. Una variable dependiente y, dos variables independientes x, z (cada una de ellas con diez niveles).

Utilizo tapply para calcular la media de y para cada nivel de x:

```
means <- tapply(dat$y,dat$x,mean)
```

Ahora estoy intentando conseguir las medias de y para cada combinación de x y z. He intentado esto si éxito:

```
means <- tapply(dat$y,dat$x & dat$z,mean)
```

Agradezco comentarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomiendo usar el paquete `dplyr`, dado que estas trabajando con `data.frame`, este paquete está orientado para trabajar con este tipo de objetos. Además si necesitaras agrupar por más variable, no es mucho codigo que tienes que cambiar de este ejemplo:

Si queremos obtener la media de la variable `mpg` de acuerdo a las combinaciones entre `am` y `vs` debemos hacer:

```r
library(dplyr)

head(mtcars)
#>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

mt_agrupada <- group_by(mtcars, am, vs)

mt_resumida <- summarise(mt_agrupada, media_mpg = mean(mpg))

mt_resumida
#>      am    vs media_mpg
#>   <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1    0.    0.      15.0
#> 2    0.    1.      20.7
#> 3    1.    0.      19.8
#> 4    1.    1.      28.4
```

Answer (score 1):

Con [`tapply()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/tapply.html) podrías hacer lo siguiente (voy a tomar el ejemplo de jbkunst):

```
tapply(mtcars$mpg, paste(mtcars$am,mtcars$vs), mean)

    0 0      0 1      1 0      1 1 
15.05000 20.74286 19.75000 28.37143
```

Como ves, usamos simplemente un `paste()` para "pegar" las dos columnas, según la documentación de [`tapply()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/tapply.html) este parametro se coerciona a un `factor` por lo que lógicamente deberíamos quedarnos únicamente con las combinaciones únicas de ambas columnas. El resultado final, como puedes ver es un `array` dónde cada columna representa una determinada combinación. En algunos casos, tal como te propuso jbkunst, una salida tabular es más clara y fácil de manejar, la cual podrías generar usando [`aggregate()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/aggregate.html), básicamente es algo así como el `GROUP BY` de `SQL` o el `group_by` de `dplyr`:

```
aggregate(mpg ~ am + vs, data=mtcars, FUN=mean)

  am vs      mpg
1  0  0 15.05000
2  1  0 19.75000
3  0  1 20.74286
4  1  1 28.37143
```